# How to make seaborn regplot partially see through (alpha)

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, linear-regression

When using seaborn `barplot`, I can specify an `alpha` to make the bars semi-translucent. However, when I try this with seaborn `regplot`, I get an error saying this is an unexpected argument.

I read the documentation online but didn't find much. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What argument are you using to specify alpha on barplot? I can't find anything like that in the docs.

Comment: The barplot docs say "Use plt.bar keyword arguments to further change the aesthetic", meaning it can take the same arguments that matplotlib bar takes, which include `alpha`.

Comment: But how? Adding plt.bar={'alpha':0.3} does not work (I tried this: sns.barplot(data=data,x=data.index, y='amplicons', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['pale red'], plt.bar={'alpha':0.3}))

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use the scatter_kws argument.  For example:

```
ax = sb.regplot(x="total_bill", 
                y="tip", 
                data=tips, 
                scatter_kws={'alpha':0.3})
```

Answer (score 1):

If we look into its [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/regression.py#L736-L760), `seaborn.regplot()` constructs two dictionaries `scatter_kws` and `line_kws` which are respectively passed off to calls to matplotlib's `scatter()` and `plot()` methods. In other words, the regression line and scatter points are plotted separately using separate kwargs. So for example, the regression line can have different `alpha=` than scatter points.

In fact, a whole host of kwargs (e.g. marker size, edgecolors, alpha) that matplotlib's `scatter()` admit are missing from `regplot()` as a keyword but they can be collected in a dictionary and passed along via the `scatter_kws` argument. Likewise for kwargs for `plot()` and `line_kws` argument.

```py
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

ax = sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=df, ci=False, 
                 scatter_kws=dict(alpha=0.5, s=30, color='blue', edgecolors='white'),
                 line_kws=dict(alpha=0.7, color='red', linewidth=3))
```

[image: result]